# Is filling different DataTables of the same DataSet a thread-safe operation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, dataset

I have many methods filling different DataTables in the same DataSet:

```
public override void FillMethod1(MyDataSet ds)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionObj))
        {
            using (SqlCommandBuilder adapterSCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds.MyTable);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Exception handling
    }
}

public override void FillMethod2(MyDataSet ds)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionObj))
        {
            using (SqlCommandBuilder adapterSCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds.MyTable2);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Exception handling
    }
}

[....]

using(MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet())
{
    FillMethod1(ds);
    FillMethod2(ds);
    [...]
}
```

And I'd like to parallelize these operation using `Task`:

```
using(MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet())
{
    Task fill1 = Task.Run(() => FillMethod1(ds));
    Task fill2 = Task.Run(() => FillMethod2(ds));
    [...]

    Task.WaitAll(fill1, fill2, [...]);
}
```

After some research I found that `DataSet` is not thread-safe, but is it safe when working on different `DataTable`?

Comment: oof; tricky question; I doubt you'll find anything formal that explicitly says "yes this is fine", but I also suspect it will indeed work fine as long as you aren't *adding* the table the the data-set in the threads (i.e. both already exists before you do this); however, my main advice here would be: **stop using `DataTable`**. That was intended as a transitional API to help people migrate over from ADO record-sets (typically from VB6); that was back in 2002. It isn't 2002 any more, and *just about any other API* is preferable to `DataTable`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot stop using DataTables because it is an old software (15 years ago) made all with DataSets. I have to find a way to do this using them, but your idea is worth a try. I can fill single DataTables and add them to the dataset in the main thread. Is that right?

Comment: I was saying add the empty tales first in the non-concurrent code, much like your code already seems to do here, but: I can't give you a "yes, that is totally fine" - the best I can say is "that'll probably work as long as each thread only talks to a different table"

Comment: Filling detached DataTables seems the way to go, if you want to be on the safe side. Filling them after attaching them to the `DataSet` sounds very risky, especially if there are [DataRelations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelation) defined between the DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class handling parallel fills on the same `DataSet`. Each fill has its own `DataSet` and it will be merged into the original one at the end of the execution.
To handle data table relations, it is possible to create a sequential list of fills that will be run in parallel with other fills. The merge method will wait for all operations to finish and merge results into the original `DataSet` (passed in the constructor)

```
public class FillParallelizer<TDataSet> : IDisposable
    where TDataSet : DataSet, new()
{
    private bool _seqFillStarted = false;
    private IList<QueryObject> _queryObjList = new List<QueryObject>();
    private Queue<FillOperation> _seqOperationBufferQueue = new Queue<FillOperation>();

    public DataSet MasterDS { get; }

    public FillParallelizer(DataSet masterDS)
    {
        MasterDS = masterDS ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(masterDS));
    }

    public FillParallelizer<TDataSet> ParallelFill(Action<TDataSet> methodAction)
    {
        if (methodAction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(methodAction));

        QueryObject queryObj = new QueryObject(methodAction);
        _queryObjList.Add(queryObj);

        return this;
    }

    public void Merge()
    {
        var taskList = _queryObjList.Select(x => x.Task).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(taskList);

        foreach (var item in _queryObjList)
        {
            MasterDS.Merge(item.TempDS);
        }
    }

    public FillParallelizer<TDataSet> SequentialFill(Action<TDataSet> action)
    {
        if(!_seqFillStarted)
        {
            _seqFillStarted = true;
        }

        if (!_seqFillStarted) throw new ArgumentException("Sequential fill not started");

        _seqOperationBufferQueue.Enqueue(new FillOperation(action));
        return this;
    }

    public FillParallelizer<TDataSet> RunSequentialFill()
    {
        _seqFillStarted = false;
        QueryObject queryObj = new QueryObject(new Queue<FillOperation>(_seqOperationBufferQueue));
        _seqOperationBufferQueue.Clear();
        _queryObjList.Add(queryObj);

        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_queryObjList == null || !_queryObjList.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var item in _queryObjList) item.Dispose();
    }

    class FillOperation
    {
        public Action<TDataSet> Action { get; }

        public FillOperation(Action<TDataSet> action)
        {
            Action = action ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        public void Run(TDataSet tempDS)
        {
            if (tempDS == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tempDS));
            Action(tempDS);
        }
    }

    class QueryObject : IDisposable
    {
        public TDataSet TempDS { get; }
        public Queue<FillOperation> FillOperationList { get; }
        public Task Task { get; }

        public QueryObject(Queue<FillOperation> fillOperationList)
        {
            TempDS = new TDataSet();
            FillOperationList = fillOperationList ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fillOperationList));
            Task =
                Task
                    .Run
                    (() =>
                    {
                        foreach (FillOperation op in FillOperationList) op.Run(TempDS);
                    }
                    );
        }

        public QueryObject(Action<TDataSet> action)
            : this(new Queue<FillOperation>(new FillOperation[] { new FillOperation(action) }))
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Task.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
using(MyDataSet myDS = new MyDataSet())
using (FillParallelizer<MyDataSet> parallelizer = new FillParallelizer<MyDataSet>(myDS))
{
    parallelizer
        .ParallelFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable1(ds))
        .ParallelFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable2(ds))

        .SequentialFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable3(ds))
        .SequentialFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable4(ds))
        .SequentialFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable5(ds))
        .RunSequentialFill()

        .ParallelFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable6(ds))
        .ParallelFill(ds => MyDAO.FillTable7(ds))

        .Merge();

    //All fills completed
}
```

Fill methods 3, 4, 5 are done sequentially but in parallel with other fills, to handle relations between tables

Comment: You are putting a lot of trust to the [`DataTable.Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge) method. More than what I would be comfortable with. As a side note, regarding disposing the `Task` of the `QueryObject` class, Stephen Toub says: [don’t bother disposing of your tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias good to know, the dispose can be removed, I'll edit. Regarding the Merge, this class should be used only in the situation I mentioned, with no changes in tables data, but only for data loading of an empty dataset

Comment: Have you made any benchmarks with this solution? I am concerned that it may not be very efficient, since essentially two datasets are filled instead of one. The increased CPU overhead of filling these objects could nullify the benefits of parallelizing the I/O access to the database.

Comment: I just noticed that time to load data in the original program dropped by 40%, but I didn't any benchmarks